# Can I separate an external drive composed of 2 hard drives while keeping data?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have an old external hard drive that is composed of two physical hard drives inside, but shows as one device in Windows. (it's twice the thickness)

Is it possible to open the enclosure and put them into another computer using SATA, while KEEPING the data intact?
I wish to do this because the enclosure is USB 2 and is very slow.

I understand this may depend on the connector type AND how the data is spanned across the drives.

Comment: Depending on the internal connectors, that might not be possible, but really it's dependent on a lot of things. Can you provide the model number, or something, so we can look up the details of the drive, without that, there isn't really enough here to answer your question.

Comment: Chances are the drives themselves will have some weird proprietary interface on them - at least, that's been my experience with older external USB *single* drives. You won't know until you open the enclosure of course. After that, the issue is that you'd be connecting them as two devices ... how does the enclosure make them look like one? RAID? Some proprietary magic? That would be harder to determine.

Comment: “Is it possible to open the enclosure and put them into another computer using SATA, while KEEPING the data intact?” - No; Your data likely is on both disks which means it is indeed RAID0 or RAID1. You will be unable to remove the disks and expect to access your data

Comment: @halldk There is a sticker that says "HDE1-1TB" on the back.

Comment: If it is RAID, is it possible to take both and re-build the RAID together?

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a faulty (i.e. incorrect) premise. An enclosure that is "*twice the thickness*" is not proof that it uses two drives.

Comment: If it is RAID, then you will have to backup the data.  If in fact you have 2 drives, then when you attach them to another computer you will have to reformat them (full erase) and then copy the data back from your backup to your freshly reformatted drives.

Comment: @bravo, I've opened many external drive cases and never seen custom connectors, if that is what you're referring to. There may be special adapters involved, but these always came off revealing connectors normal for the drive type. I won't say this is always the case, and our experiences appear to differ. Further, I think the bigger consideration is how the two drives are spanned to a single visible drive. THAT may be the custom thing, I think. Or it may be a pretty standard RAID.

Comment: @music2myear - I've only opened maybe 3 or 4, and all of them were unusable on standard SATA connectors - maybe I'm unlucky, or you're lucky :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on more factors than you have given us, so I will speak in generalities.

First, it is possible the drives will have non-standard connectors. Some of the commentors note this is common. My own experience indicates it is not common, and that the drives you'll find inside may need to have odd connectors removed (they might even be glued to the drive) but ultimately the drives inside will probably be able to be physically connected into other cases or a regular computer.

Second, HOW the drives are configured to show as a single array seems to me to be the bigger problem. Assuming this is done using standard protocols and methods, such as RAID, it is still uncommon to be able to take drives controlled by on RAID controller and connect them to a different RAID controller and expect them to behave as they did on the first. If the device is NOT using standard methods for this, even that chance is gone.

The general advice for moving drives stands here: backup your data first. This is the best answer and it will apply in your situation as in any other.

Backup the data and you'll have it safe regardless what happens to the device, THEN open up the device and do what you want to do. If you're lucky you won't need the backup. But if a more likely outcome occurs, your data will be safe.

If your current device is non-functional now, causing you to look into these options, you should follow the various guides for data recovery if the data is important. There are thoroughly answered questions on this site regarding that process already.